# Rails asset pipeline - Page specific css

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline

I have  a website that contains a registration page on the front end.
It also contains an admin panel which uses an admin theme.
Since the javascripts and css files of the theme are placed on assets folder, they will be loaded on the admin pages as well as on the FRONT END.

Is there a way to organise the theme files on the asset folder so that they are not loaded on the front end?

Answer (score 0):

Add an admin_application.(css & js) file and do require all the css and js used for admin panel into that and stub all the front_end assets.

You can stub the file like

in js

//= stub file.js

in css

*= stub file.css

**Note**: You should use different layout for both front_end and admin_panel.

Comment: Does this get precompiled when you run rake assets:precompile ?

Comment: Add Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( file_name )
for pre compilation in assets.rb